# Making a SQL query more efficient

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

okay, so our server here at work isn't the best, and when I run this query it really throttles down everyone using anything on our server. Is there anyway I can make this query more efficient? I'd like to be able to run the query without everyone freaking out and say we are going slow 
the query basically outputs

```
Order Number | OrderDate | Sku | quantity | item price | our shipping $ | number indicating if it is paid | authorizeddate | amazonorderid | ebaybuyerid | Tax | TaxAmount | Shipping |Shipping Amt
```

The query returns everything I need, but I feel it could definitely be rewritten. I tried but it kept slowing down the server with queries that weren't working any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT g.ordernumber, 
       g.orderdate, 
       p.sku, 
       p.quantity, 
       p.name, 
       p.unitprice, 
       s.shipmentcost AS OurPrice, 
       e.rollupeffectivecheckoutstatus, 
       ' '            AS wonder, 
       ' '            AS AmazonorderID, 
       e.ebaybuyerid, 
       f.type         AS TAX, 
       f.amount       AS TAXCHARGE, 
       x.type         AS SHIPPING, 
       x.amount       AS ShippingCharge 
FROM   [ShipWorks].[dbo].[orderitem] p, 
       [ShipWorks].[dbo].[order] g, 
       [Shipworks].[dbo].[shipment] s, 
       [Shipworks].[dbo].[ebayorder] e, 
       [ShipWorks].[dbo].[ordercharge] f, 
       [ShipWorks].[dbo].[ordercharge] x 
WHERE  g.orderid = s.orderid 
       AND f.orderid = g.orderid 
       AND x.orderid = g.orderid 
       AND g.orderid = p.orderid 
       AND e.orderid = g.orderid 
       AND f.type = 'TAX' 
       AND x.type = 'SHIPPING' 
       AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), orderdate, 120)BETWEEN 
           ( '2013-09-16' ) AND ( '2013-09-17' ) 
UNION 
SELECT t.ordernumber, 
       t.orderdate, 
       i.sku, 
       i.quantity, 
       i.name, 
       i.unitprice, 
       g.shipmentcost, 
       ' ' AS RollupEffectiveCheckoutStatus, 
       r.authorizeddate, 
       ' ' AS AmazonorderID, 
       ' ' AS EbayBuyerID, 
       f.type, 
       f.amount, 
       x.type, 
       x.amount 
FROM   [ShipWorks].[dbo].[order] t, 
       [ShipWorks].[dbo].[prostoresorder] r, 
       [ShipWorks].[dbo].[orderitem] i, 
       [ShipWorks].[dbo].[shipment] g, 
       [ShipWorks].[dbo].[ordercharge] f, 
       [ShipWorks].[dbo].[ordercharge] x 
WHERE  t.orderid = r.orderid 
       AND t.orderid = i.orderid 
       AND t.orderid = g.orderid 
       AND t.orderid = f.orderid 
       AND t.orderid = x.orderid 
       AND f.type = 'TAX' 
       AND x.type = 'SHIPPING' 
       AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), orderdate, 120)BETWEEN 
           ( '2013-09-16' ) AND ( '2013-09-17' ) 
UNION 
SELECT t.ordernumber, 
       t.orderdate, 
       i.sku, 
       i.quantity, 
       i.name, 
       i.unitprice, 
       q.shipmentcost, 
       ' ' AS RollupEffectiveCheckoutStatus, 
       ' ' AS AuthorizedDate, 
       a.amazonorderid, 
       ' ' AS EbayBuyerID, 
       f.type, 
       f.amount, 
       x.type, 
       x.amount 
FROM   [ShipWorks].[dbo].[order] t, 
       [ShipWorks].[dbo].[amazonorder] a, 
       [ShipWorks].[dbo].[orderitem] i, 
       [ShipWorks].[dbo].[shipment] q, 
       [ShipWorks].[dbo].[ordercharge] f, 
       [ShipWorks].[dbo].[ordercharge] x 
WHERE  t.orderid = a.orderid 
       AND t.orderid = f.orderid 
       AND t.orderid = x.orderid 
       AND t.orderid = i.orderid 
       AND t.orderid = q.orderid 
       AND f.type = 'TAX' 
       AND x.type = 'SHIPPING' 
       AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), orderdate, 120)BETWEEN 
           ( '2013-09-16' ) AND ( '2013-09-17' ) `
```

Comment: could you format that lump of code so it is readble?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: internet is full of online formatters

Comment: and stop using those implict joins, they make code much harder to troubleshoot and can have errors causing accidental cross joins. They are a SQL anitpapttern

Comment: Yes, how about some `ON` conditions on your joins, it will probably fix your speed.

Comment: ANd what is the data type of orderdate? What are you converting it to char?

Comment: IF you must run queries like this against a transactional database, you should consider including `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` at the top.

Comment: And what indexes do you have on those tables

Comment: @EkoostikMartin really? Does NOLOCK make the query fast, or just potentially inaccurate? Sometimes you want blocking so that you can be confident in the result. Please don't suggest to people that you fix performance by changing locking hints.

Comment: Are the three data sets from each of the unions mutually exclusive? In other words would you get the same result set if you used UNION ALL instead? Not checking for duplicates tends to speed things up.

Comment: @EkoostikMarting read uncommitted is not a turbo button. There are clearly problems with the query. Address the actual problems.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I'm not so much worried about making this query fast, but about changing the fact that it is blocking other queries in a transactional database (as the OP suggested was happening). I assumed this query was used for reporting since it contains 2 unions and hardcoded dates...

Comment: @Vishal that won't affect query speed but it does make it easier to read

Comment: @EkoostikMartin for reporting especially, in a lot of situations you WANT blocking.  For instance would you want to see uncommited withdrawals in a banking system?  I doubt it.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin the OP asked how to make this query fast. Which should affect this query even when in isolation. Very dangerous to recommend dirty and phantom reads without explaining the pitfalls or understanding if those symptoms are acceptable. Sometimes they are, but there's this phrase about assuming...

Comment: @JNK I was thinking more in terms of joining on the right fields resulting in less records to be fetched and then applied `where` on.

Comment: marc_s what do you mean , seperated list. Sorry I didnt format the SQL correctly to everyone. vishal can you please give me an example of an ON, I was never the best with inner join or JOIN ON, HLGEM, that tables are contstantly updated. Is there anyway to have an index constantly update. I use the SQL server management studio, I'm not quite sure how to index them. @HLGEM not quite sure. the tables have to be unioned because I need orders that are ebay(first query) (online store I own) is the second and third (amazon) I use the amazon id to seperate if it is amazon

Comment: authorizationdate to see if it is paid in my online store(ebay and amazon wont have a good date in for it. it doesnt exist with those stores. I use ebayid and rollupeffectivestatus to see if order is paid in ebay. These are tables from a program called Shipworks database. They don't offer these types of reports so I had to try to implement myself

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Both good points, it was not responsible for me to recommend dirty reads without knowing the OP's exact situation or presenting the (sometimes significant) downfalls of using read uncommitted.

Comment: I only need to run this query once a day, if that, but my boss may request more so I just wanted it to be able to work with considerably slowing down the speeds for everyone

Comment: @HLGEM I had to convert the date because it had seconds and such on it

Comment: @HLGEM Ive ran plenty of queries with that date convert and havent had many issues though.

Comment: Stop converting the date. Use >= '20130916' AND < '20130917'. BETWEEN does not make sense here at all, anyway. See https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx and https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Comment: @aaron bertrand That makes sense, do you think this will improve time to execute?

Comment: @JakeIson it won't be slower, that's for sure. And if that column has an index, it may be able to use a seek instead of scan.

Comment: @JakeIson You seem to be repeating exactly the same join and `WHERE` three times for `order,orderitem,shipment,ordercharge,ordercharge`. This can definitely be avoided. What is the cardinality of `orderid` in the three tables `ebayorder,prostoresorder,amazonorder`? Is it unique in all those tables?

Comment: @MartinSmith the orderid is the same, couldnt get it working without doing union only things that should be unique to a table are ebaybuyerid,rollupeffectivestatus these should be unique to ebay table, amazonorderid should be unique to amazonorder table and  authorizeddate to the prostores order table. All tables are linked by orderid

Comment: @AaronBertrand you say if that column has an index, how can I index all tables and colums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three branches of the `UNION` are pretty similar and repeat the same `JOIN` and `WHERE` on 5 of the 6 tables.

You could try

```
SELECT o.ordernumber,
       o.orderdate,
       oi.sku,
       oi.quantity,
       oi.name,
       oi.unitprice,
       s.shipmentcost AS OurPrice,
       ca.rollupeffectivecheckoutstatus,
       ca.wonder,
       ca.AmazonorderID,
       ca.ebaybuyerid,
       oc1.type       AS TAX,
       oc1.amount     AS TAXCHARGE,
       oc2.type       AS SHIPPING,
       oc2.amount     AS ShippingCharge
FROM   [dbo].[order] o
       JOIN [dbo].[orderitem] oi
         ON o.orderid = oi.orderid
       JOIN [dbo].[shipment] s
         ON o.orderid = s.orderid
       JOIN [dbo].[ordercharge] oc1
         ON oc1.orderid = o.orderid
            AND oc1.type = 'TAX'
       JOIN [dbo].[ordercharge] oc2
         ON oc2.orderid = o.orderid
            AND oc2.type = 'SHIPPING'
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT rollupeffectivecheckoutstatus, NULL, NULL, ebaybuyerid
                    FROM   [dbo].[ebayorder] e
                    WHERE  e.orderid = o.orderid
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL, authorizeddate, NULL, NULL
                    FROM   [dbo].[prostoresorder] p
                    WHERE  p.orderid = o.orderid
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL, '', amazonorderid, NULL
                    FROM   [dbo].[amazonorder] a
                    WHERE  a.orderid = o.orderid) ca(rollupeffectivecheckoutstatus, wonder, AmazonorderID, ebaybuyerid)
WHERE  orderdate >= '20130916'
       AND orderdate < '20130918'
```

Comment: I have to try it on sunday, so I will let you know how it goes! Thanks for trying to help. I'm hoping this works !

Comment: @JakeIson - If it doesn't then post the execution plan so we can see if you are missing some useful indexes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this took care of the issue, I'm still working it out for Amazon tables, but I think I have it now. Our server is not the best as it is. I can't figure out how to change swap memory and used memory because the swap memory is much too high, but thank you for the query, it runs much faster, thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First do the typical database optimization things, like I would check how much memory is allocated to your database.  This could really help things out as it might prevent data being written to disk in the processing.

Do you need to increase the server hardware?

Does this query need to run once per day?  If so setup a cron job so that it runs when there is no one at work.

If you are still having problems you may need to archive data so that it is not in the table that is active, and you can also pull the data into an application that can do your unions.

Comment: MySql? Question is tagged SQL Server (and I don't think memory allocation defaults work the same way).

Comment: This is SQL server not mysql, you may want to rephase your answer to remove anything mysql specific.

Comment: how do I archive the data for the sql, index it? can someone point me in the direction on how to, I've never done it. Also how do I allocate memory to the database? Could I allocate more to make it faster?